# Wordpress links showing 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I installed wordpress in my local machine and everything works fine.

When i uploaded to server connect via ssh to ubuntu machine, the permalinks were not working.

Here is my website

http://piorganic.in/

[image: wordpress page]
[image: permalink structure]
[image: generated htaccess]

On my ubuntu machine the wordpress folder is in **var/www/html/xxx**

I enabled mod_rewrite in apache2 and also updated the generated .htaccess file with WINSCP.

[image]

[image: folder permissions]

Couldnt figure out where the mistake is. Looking forward for a valuable help.

Comment: Look's like you didn't install rewrite module, install it. After installing, you can update the permalink.

Comment: Its enabled and i mentioned it already. I also attached the screenshot

Comment: You restarted apache after installation? Also make sure there is proper permission given to the folder

Comment: yes. attached the folder permissions snapshot too

Comment: http://piorganic.in `Not Found`? Looks like you have posted you wordpress in sub directory?

Comment: I got it. I missed to configure virtual host in etc/apache2/sites-enabled. Changed to Allowoverride All

Comment: Okay. Great worked now?